# Retrieving local IP before a connection is made

Tags: c, linux, networking, tcp, routes

I am trying to determine which local IP would be used on a socket for a TCP connection towards a given host on Linux, using C.

Let me make an example. I could connect my socket and use getsockname() on the file descriptor to get the local ip (and local TCP port); but can I do this without opening the connection?

I could read the routing table and make a decision based on that - but the networking subsystem must have that algorithm already, for when the connection is actually open. In short, I'd like to know if there is an API to access the routing algorithms without having to parse the rules myself or opening an actual connection. The solution - if any - will probably be Linux only but that's OK.

EDIT: someone on IRC suggested I create a UDP socket and use connect() on it. No network is used at that point but I should be able to use getsockname() on it

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netlink  This is still opening a connection but I am not sure you consider it an "actual" connection or not.

Comment: OK... I am not sure I understand how netlink would give me the local IP used to contact a remote host. Would you clarify?

Comment: I don't think there is a painless way to do what you want.  This is an area in which I don't have much experience but I think you will have to read through the tables yourself and I think netlink is the standard way to do that hence the suggestion in a comment rather than a definitive answer.

Comment: Ohh you mean use netlink to read the routing table :) now I got it.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I know to this is what traceroute does.  Send a packet with a TTL of 1 and see which interface the ICMP return comes in on.  As I recall there are lots of incompatibilities between different hosts, so there's probably several different types of messages you might need to send/receive to get the data you need.

Comment: I would think that a solution with no side effects (in this case, actual usage of the network) exists, as the routing table and interface description should be enough to get that info.

Comment: I'd like to think so, but the use case is rare enough that I doubt there's anything pre-existing.  Here's hoping someone knows a way.  I'm guessing you are trying to do some kind of active load balancing?

Comment: Not really - I am dealing with a system that has multiple interfaces and needs to display info about the network. In an effort to reduce the amount of data on the screen I would need to know the details (mainly the local IP address) that would be used to contact a given host. I'd like to avoid "unnecessary" network traffic at this point.